# to_representation in django restframework does not work with custom serializers.SerializerMethodField

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I was bit confused about having custom structure with custom field, attached my reference implementation. If you see **do_representation** you output was not as expected, anyone know why is it so?

```
class ImageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    thumb = serializers.ImageField()
    class Meta:
        model = Image
        fields = ('thumb',)

class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    def product_url(self,obj):
        request = self.context['request']
        return request.build_absolute_uri(reverse('product', args=(obj.slug,)))

    url = serializers.SerializerMethodField('product_url')
    images = ImageSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ('url', 'images', 'id')

    def to_representation(self,product):
        raise Exception(product.url) # Not working
        raise Exception(product.images) # Not working
        raise Exception(product.id) # Working
```

Here is the error message

```
'Product' object has no attribute 'url'
```

**Note:** But if I don't override with to_representation then json response has url field

**My workaround**

**Models**

```
class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=256,null=True,blank=False)

class ProductImage(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey('Product',on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,blank=True,related_name='product_images')
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='product/',null=True)
    thumb = ImageSpecField(source='image', 
                        processors=[ResizeToFill(100, 1100)], 
                        format='JPEG', 
                        options={'quality': 70})
```

**Actual Output**

```
{
   "count":5,
   "next":"http://localhost:8000/api/products/?format=json&page=2",
   "previous":null,
   "results":[
      {
         "id":1,
         "images":[
            {
               "thumb":"http://localhost:8000/media/CACHE/images/product/Product1/fee2eb25a1d7b954632dd377aca39995.jpg"
            },
            {
               "thumb":"http://localhost:8000/media/CACHE/images/product/Product2/a279c5057bb5ee6e06945f98d89cc411.jpg"
            }
         ],
         "url":"http://localhost:8000/product/wooden-furniture/"
      }
   ]
}
```

**Expected Output**

```
{
   "count":5,
   "next":"http://localhost:8000/api/products/?format=json&page=2",
   "previous":null,
   "results":[
      {
         "id":1,
         "images":[
               "thumb":"http://localhost:8000/media/CACHE/images/product/Product1/fee2eb25a1d7b954632dd377aca39995.jpg",
               "popup":"http://localhost:8000/media/CACHE/images/product/Product2/a279c5057bb5ee6e06945f98d89cc411.jpg" # Will work on it once I achieve it wil popup
         ],
         "url":"http://localhost:8000/product/wooden-furniture/"
      }
   ]
}
```

**My custom structure tryout**

```
def to_representation(self,obj):
    return {
        'id': obj.id,
        'images': {
            'thumb': obj.images # May be I have to work to get only first image here
        },
        'url': obj.url
    }
```

Comment: In your case `product` is instance of the model `Product` and as i understand your model has no the `url` attr.

Comment: @BearBrown yes exactly, but how can I achieve in my case. I have 2 custom fields and I need to form structure with to_representation.. Any Idea??

Comment: the `SerializerMethodField` in the answer looks like a good idea, why you want  the `to_representation` way?

Comment: Because I want my own structure instead of using default rest framework structure.. My requirement :(

Comment: please show your models and json you want to release

Comment: @BearBrown yes updated my question with maximum information that I can

Answer (score 1):

As you are respresnting the data by your own. So you have to do other things by own.

Try this,

```
class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    def product_url(self,obj):
        request = self.context['request']
        return request.build_absolute_uri(reverse('product', args=(obj.slug,)))

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ('url', 'images', 'id')

    def to_representation(self, product):
        image_objs = ProductImage.objects.filter(product=product)
        images = ImageSerializer(image_objs, many=True)

        return {
            "id": product.id,
            "images" images.data,
            "url": self.product_url(product)
        }
```